# Django Update view doesn't update an object during test

Tags: python, django

I'm writing tests for my views and I'm stuck with the UpdateView and the POST request. For this simple test I try just to change first_name but assertion fails. What am I doing wrong?
However, when I call the response.context it gives me that (it has the updated employee):

```
[{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x7f070ed6eee0>>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: POST '/employees/7/update'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: testuser@test.com>>, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x7f070ecb33d0>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x7f070ed1b130>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40}}, {}, {'object': <Employee: John Smith>, 'employee': <Employee: John Smith>, 'form': <EmployeeUpdateForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(first_name;last_name;user;position;reports_to;birthday;hire_date;address;phone_number;pfp)>, 'view': <employees.views.EmployeesUpdateView object at 0x7f070ed1b310>}]
```

The test:

```
class TestEmployeesUpdateView(TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.test_user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='test_user', email=
        'testuser@test.com', password='Testing12345')
    self.test_employee = Employee.objects.create(
        first_name='Bob', last_name='Smith', user=self.test_user, position='SM',
        birthday=date(year=1995, month=3, day=20),
        hire_date=date(year=2019, month=2, day=15),
        address='...',
    )
    self.client = Client()


def test_updateview_post(self):
    self.client.force_login(user=self.test_user)
    response = self.client.post(reverse('employees:employee-update', kwargs={'pk': self.test_employee.pk}), {'first_name': 'John'})
    self.test_employee.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(self.test_employee.first_name, 'John')
```

The view:

```
class EmployeesUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model = Employee
template_name = 'employees/employee_details.html'
form_class = EmployeeUpdateForm
```

And the error:

```
FAIL: test_updateview_post (employees.tests.test_views.TestEmployeesUpdateView)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/main/dev/project1/employees/tests/test_views.py", line 63, in test_updateview_post
    self.assertEqual(self.test_employee.first_name, 'John')
AssertionError: 'Bob' != 'John'
- Bob
+ John
```

Edit: typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is not valid, check response.context['form'].errors for errors.

Comment: Indeed, I checked the form and it wasn't valid. I fixed it. And now I did the manual test in the browser: form works fine, view works fine, the employee object is updated as intended. But still my unit test fails. That's not cool, I want to test my system via automated tests first and do manual tests for the second.

Comment: Add a line print(response.context['form'].errors) after the response = self.client.post..., what does it say?

Comment: It says this: "<ul class="errorlist"><li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li><li>position<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. CEO is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>". I'm confused how to properly pass value for the choices field. I tried to change the type of field to Select and my form throws an error.

Comment: Form complains about the user and the position. The user should be the user's id, and the position should be a string (like 'SM' in your setup code).

When the user clicks Submit the form posts all fields, not just changes. So your {'first_name': 'John'} is not enough, it should be something like {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'user': self.test_user.id, 'position': 'SM' ...}

Comment: Thank you vey much, Ivan. You are right, that was the problem: I had to fill every field of the form to pass the test. I thought I can pass only one field which I want to update. Now all my tests work properly!

Answer (score 1):

You got a typo in your test_updateview_post()
It is {'frist_name': 'John'}

Judging from you User, Employee Model I don't see any frist_name

Comment: Thanks, but even when I fixed a typo there are no changes in my test case.